# Create signed release binaries and distribute with custom repository (debian)

Tags: gnupg, code-signing, debian

I have been tasked to create a custom repository with signed binaries for download. Our CEO explicitly mentioned that he wants the binary signed by himself and his business parther.

I set up a webserver, and created a secure apt environment with `dpkg-sig`. So basically for someone to download and install the package, they add to the `sources.list`, and `apt-key add` the repository key.

I am a bit confused by the details though. So as far as I can see, `dpkg-sig` is to sign the package and allow secure apt. Not to sign the binaries themselves. Also, it just uses one key for signing.

Thus, in order to fulfill our CEOs requirement, I was wanting to sign the binary itself with `gpg` and two keys:
`gpg --sign -u KEY1 -u KEY2 ourpkg.deb`

That actually creates a new (signed) file though, so this means that the original binary would have to be extracted in order for it to be installed.

What seems right is to `gpg --armor --detach-sig ourpkg.deb` which then creates a separate file, and the original `deb` is ready to be installed via `apt-get` on a client machine. This however means that the actual verification would be left to the user, and the `apt` system just verifies that the `apt-key` is trusted and installs the package right away.

Am I going right about this? Or should I maybe include some script into the installation package which actually runs the verification first or something? What's the point of (double) signing the binary if the system installs it right away anyway?

Any suggestion highly appreciated.